# wordpress as law draft discussion site

Tags: plugin-recommendation

I need to build a site to openly discuss the draft of legal law. Every person interested in the law will can leave a comment for each article. Comments should be upvoted and downvoted. Also, every person should be able to sign off the support of the draft.

Any ideas which plugins can help me?

thanks a lot for your answers !

Answer (score 0):

I prefer this way...

1. Drafts - Custom Post Types
2. Comments - You'll need to design the comments template in such a way that it looks more like a complete feedback.
3. For upvote / downvote on comments, you'll need a ratings plugin that allows you to rate comments. Or you can do it yourself and use comment meta to store the rating points.

What say?

Comment: Hi, pretty much I've thought it should be :) But what particular plugin can I use for upvote / downvote ?

Comment: Check out GD Star Ratings. It will do the job. But let me mind you, its very heavy on the system and space!